# How to embed a flash (.swf) file into asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, flash

How to display a flash (.swf) file into asp.net ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

got this from YouTube

```
<object width="425" height="344">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Xt5t9BO6xkA&hl=en&fs=1"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Xt5t9BO6xkA&hl=en&fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></embed>
</object>
```

You'd only need this:

```
<object width="425" height="344">
  <embed src="PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: It's IE, what do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Use the SWF object javascript helper
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

- it is industry standard
- it hide the differences of flash initializations between browsers
- it allows you to specify flash variables in browser independed way
- it allows you to specify required version of the flash player

See example below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {
playlistURL: "playlist.xml",
skinURL: "skin-transp-grey.swf",
width: "400", 
height: "300",
continuous : "true"
};

var params = {
allowscriptaccess: "always",
allowfullscreen: "true",
};

var attributes = {
id: "mediaplayer1",
name: "mediaplayer1"
};

swfobject.embedSWF("mediaplayer.swf", "video", "400", "300", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params,attributes);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using [**FlashEmbed**](http://flash.flowplayer.org/), a JavaScript tool that you can use to embed Flash objects to you website.

It is simple to use and has many advantages:

- it's very simple: just use `flashembed("flash10", "/swf/flash10.swf")` for example, if you don't need anything special you don't have to study much.
- there a lots of demos on the site how to configure the tool
- jQuery support: flashembed is designed for for scripters in mind with polished programming API together with a support for jQuery selectors.
- JSON configuration: when supplying configuration for Flash objects the values can be complex JavaScript objects with arrays, strings, functions and other objects.
- Size: the plugin weights around 5 kb when minified.

If you like you could write an **ASP.NET server control**, which renders the HTML you'll need on that page:

1. Includes external script resource link using `ScriptManager.RegisterScriptResource(...)` (once per page)
2. Render the flashebmed script using `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScript(...)` (for ever y flash you want to embed on a page)
3. Write some useful properties like src, name etc.

Then, use the control in your pages this way for example:

```
<myControls:FlashEmbed runat="server" id="Flash1" Name="Clock" Src="/swf/clock.swf" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The embed is handled via what you output in HTML -- there's nothing specific about it ASP.NET.

Put another way, the same way you output any other HTML `<B>, <I>`, etc., you can output something like:

```
<object width="425" height="344"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/IZKl4nA5cmM&hl=en&fs=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/IZKl4nA5cmM&hl=en&fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></embed></object>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML5 embed tag alone would do the trick in all modern browsers.

```
<embed src="FILE" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="X" height="Y" />
```