# How can I display flashfilms in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash

In my current project I have the following situation: A multipage PDF gets rendered by some nasty software into a flash film. My job is to display that rendered flashfilm (will be rendered as file) in my current asp.net application.

I don't know what the rendered flashfilm will look like, but I assume all flash files behave the same? Or are there differences I should know about.

What options do I have to display that flashfilm? Does ASP.net support some built-in object oriented control that allows me to display flashfilm?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668846/how-to-embed-a-flash-swf-file-into-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily display any flash file by using a [plethora of techniques](http://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+embed+flash). And it's not built-in, but there are a number of controls and other libraries built by the community to deal with displaying flash content in asp.net, such as *Flash Control* (http://flash-control.net/)

Answer (score 0):

what you refer to as a flash film is a .swf file. the recommended way to embed .swf files is SWFOBject , a javascript library

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

now, i'm no asp specialist , but you may be able to fill the gap between javascript & asp.

hope it helps!