# ASP.NET: Call .swf in .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash

I'm trying the code below but its not working..

```
<object width="425" height="344">
  <embed src="C:\Users\fortress\Desktop\AppointmentApp.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344"></embed>
</object>
```

Also tried this. Not working also.

```
<object width="425" height="344">
  <embed src="~/Styles/Images/AppointmentApp.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344"></embed>
</object>
```

Problem:

1. The swf is not displaying.
2. I saw an error when I open the designer saying that "A control type was not specified or the specified type could not be found." I already import the shockwave-player for flash but still this error appeared..
3. I want also that the .swf will be fullscreen played in .aspx.

I'm newbie in ASP.net.. SO yeah, please explain also the code if its okay...

Here's the output in client-side:

[image]

Here's the whole code for my client-side:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: @Dev, that's the code I'm using...The error for that is number 1 and 2

Comment: have a look at @se_pavel answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668846/how-to-embed-a-flash-swf-file-into-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't ASP.NET, this is HTML.  It might be served to the client by an ASP.NET server-side application, but that makes no difference to the client.

As far as HTML goes, your paths are broken.  In both cases:

- C:\Users\fortress\Desktop\AppointmentApp.swf
- ~/Styles/Images/AppointmentApp.swf

In the first case you're referencing a file system path.  This wouldn't work on any client computer which doesn't have that file.  If the file is on the web server then no client will be able to access the web server's `C:` drive.  In the second case you're using a server-side relative path with a `~`, and no client will be able to make sense of that.

When the page renders, the path needs to reference the file from the *client's* perspective.  Something like this:

- /Styles/Images/AppointmentApp.swf

Or perhaps:

- ../../Styles/Images/AppointmentApp.swf

Or whatever the path is from the rendered page to the SWF file.

I'm not *100%* sure if this works well for `object`/`embed` tags, but you *might* be able to use the `~` path reference if you make the tag a server-side control.  That should just be as easy as adding `runat="server"` to the tag:

```
<embed runat="server" src="~/Styles/Images/AppointmentApp.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344"></embed>
```

This would indicate to the ASP.NET application that the control needs some server-side processing before it's rendered to the client, and that processing would include evaluating relative paths.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer...but still the same.. I'm having this error "A control type was not specified or the specified type could not be found." Did you think I need something to add in the designer?

Comment: @user2826499: Where/when do you get that error?  When working with things like `object` and `embed` tags the Visual Studio design view could very easily break, but the application still works just fine.  (Honestly, I recommend not even using design view and just writing the HTML.)

Comment: when I switch in design mode in ASP.NET...But then I test your code and run it its display nothing..just an empty page... :( I'm having trouble with this one...

Comment: @user2826499: Did you just blindly copy and paste my code or did you actually edit the path to point to the URL of the SWF file?  I don't know the URL of some file on your computer, you need to determine that.

Comment: @user2826499: The URL from your question?  Which one?  And did you change it as suggested by my answer?  Or make the element a server-side object?  Be specific, I can't see the changes you're making.

Comment: @Davis, I just paste this code to my .aspx 
<embed runat="server" src="~/Styles/Images/AppointmentApp.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344"></embed>

because that URL is the one that I'm using...

Comment: @user2826499: And what does that become in the client-side HTML?  If it becomes a client-usable URL, does the browser make a request for it?  What is the server's response to that request?

Comment: @Davis, For the client-side..It's displaying nothing when I tried to run it in the browser [google chrome]...

Comment: @Davis, I edit my question..I put there the screenshots in my client-side

Comment: @user2826499: There's no HTML at all?  For just that tag or the entire page?  The latter sounds like a very different problem unrelated to the URL used in the markup.  If by "nothing" you mean that it's not loading the SWF, that's exactly what you need to be debugging by looking at the actual HTML and using the browser's debugging tools to see if it's trying to load that URL.  I can't debug this for you.

Comment: @user2826499: Looks like the server-side tags aren't automatically updating the "value" or "src" attributes then, assuming you made those into server-side tags.  If that's the case then you're going to need to use the correct client-usable URLs manually, or embed something like a call to "ResolveUrl" (I think, it's been a while since I've had to use WebForms) to translate the URL before sending it to the client.  The bottom line is that browsers can't use a "~" in the URL like that.  They would be looking for an actual path called "~" which isn't there.

Comment: @Davis, so that means the URL should be in the server-side? not in the client-side just to make it appear?

Comment: @user2826499: No, the client-side code needs the URL of the SWF file so it can request that file from the web server.  But it needs that URL to be the *actual* URL used to request the file.  The URL you're using, with the "~", is only understood server-side.  A browser can't resolve the "~" path specifier.  So you either need to use server-side code to convert that path to something the browser can use or manually specify a URL the browser can use.

Comment: @Davis, Got it! I'll do your suggestions..thanks for helping me even though our conversation is so long you still tried to help me to understand..hahaha thank you so much for your tips..! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need both `<param>` movie tag and `<embed>`.  Try this:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344">
<param name="movie" value="/Styles/Images/AppointmentApp.swf">
  <embed src="/Styles/Images/AppointmentApp.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344"></embed>
</object>
```

Good luck!

Comment: hmm...and your AppointmentApp.swf is in the /Styles/Images?

also I don't think you can use ~/ on these tags.  In order to use ~, this tag needs to have runat="server", but I don't think these tags will support that.

Comment: Hello..its working now I just copied it again..Thanks for the Help...hmmm...do you know also how to call an swf with xml?

Comment: Great!  
Not sure what you meant by calling a SWF with XML.  XML is more encapsulating data, not displaying SWF.